# Primitive-ability of a function

Tags: integration, analysis

Prove that the function $f:{R}\to{R}$ is primitive-able(does this term exist in English?) and find one of its primitives.

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1-x & x<1 \\
x^2-2x+1 & x \geq 1
\end{array}\right.$$

How does integrability differ from primitive-ability? I know that a function can be integrable and not primitive-able, or vice-versa. I know that for a function to be primitive-able it must have the Darboux property(intermediate value property). But how do I go about solving this function?

Comment: What do you mean by a function $f$ being primitive-able? That there exists $F$ so that $F'=f$? Then things depend on the kind of integrals and derivatives you are looking at. Normal (strong) derivatives are different from distributional derivatives and there are many ways to integrate (Newton, Riemann, Lebesgue and others). Can you add more details?

Comment: It's a question from an admission exam for computer science/mathematics . It doesn't give any more details. As for $f$ being primitive-able, I know that it has to have the intermediate value property and there should be a function $F$ so that $F'=f$, like you said. I didn't study any integrals other than Riemann - the simplest one to define.

Comment: I would say the Newton integral is even easier to define. That is, $F$ is *defined* to be an indefinite integral of $f$ if and only if $F'=f$. The fundamental theorem of calculus in the very definition and integrability coincides with primitive-ability. Let me also remark that any Riemann integrable function has a primitive if you interpret the derivative in the weak sense. But for the usual definition of the derivative the problem is not that trivial.